# How to change a particular value of a list present in a matrix

Tags: r

I am working on color classification. I am giving input as positive and negative angles and also angles represent RGB colors. When the angle is negative or exceeds 255, how do i change the negative value to zero or angle exceeding 255 to 255. Here matrix contains the list of angles. Each list represent RGB.
I am posting a piece of code here:

```
library(rgl)

som <- function()
{
  rad2deg = function(rad)
  {
    return((180 * rad) / pi)
  }

  n <- 3
  m <- 30
  l <- 15
  alpha <- .09

  a <- list("numeric", n)
  wij <- matrix(list(), nrow = m, ncol = m)

  #Initailize the weight matrix
  for(x1 in 1:m)
  {
    for(x2 in 1:m)
    {
      a <- runif((n-1), -pi/12, pi/12)
      a<- rad2deg(a)
      a <- c(a*8+128,255)
      wij[[x1,x2]] <- a
     }
  }

  s <- runif((n-1), -pi/12, pi/12)

  theta <- rad2deg(s[1])
  theta <- 128+theta*8

  phi <- rad2deg(s[2])
  phi <- 128+phi*8

  x <- as.integer(l* sin(s[1]) + m/2)
  y <- as.integer(l*sin(s[2]) + m/2)

  for(x1 in 1:m)
  {
    for(x2 in 1:m)
      wij[[x1,x2]] <- wij[[x1,x2]] +((x1-x)+(x2-y))*alpha*(wij[[x1,x2]]-c(theta,phi,255))
  } 

  for(x1 in 1:m)
  {
    for(x2 in 1:m)
      rgl.spheres(x=x1, y=x2, col=rgb(t(wij[[x1,x2]]), maxColorValue =          255), radius = 1 )
   }
 }    

som()
```

I am getting the following errors:

> 1. Error in rgb(t(wij[[x1, x2]]), maxColorValue = 255) :    color intensity 259, not in 0:255
> 2. Error in rgb(t(wij[[x1, x2]]), maxColorValue = 255) :    color intensity -5, not in 0:255

Do we have any method to represent negative numbers and the value exceeding 255   in RGB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

`get_valid_number <- function(number) {pmax(0,pmin(255,number))}`

to produce a number between 0 and 255:

`numbers <- c(-5, 42, 259)
get_valid_number(numbers)`

`[1]   0  42 255`